# Turn a system of $N$ quadratic equation into $2^N$ (?) linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

**Test case:**

Consider the following system of quadratic equations:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a x^2+2bxy+cy^2=\lambda x\\ 
bx^2+2cxy+dy^2=\lambda y
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ are constants.

There are $2^2=4$ possible solutions. How could turn this system of 2 quadratic equations into a set of 4 (coupled) linear equations? That is to say, find a set of constants such that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3y_1+a_4y_2=\lambda x_1\\ 
b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3y_1+b_4y_2=\lambda x_2 \\ 
c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3y_1+c_4y_2=\lambda y_1 \\ 
d_1x_1+d_2x_2+d_3y_1+d_4y_2=\lambda y_2\\ 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
**General Case:**

Consider a general system of $N$ quadratic coupled equations where $x\in \mathbb{C}^N$ is the unknown:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{jk}^N T_{ijk}x_jx_k=\lambda x_i,\quad \forall 1\leq i \leq N
\end{equation}
Where $\lambda$ and $T_{ijk}$ are simply constants (and $T$ fully symmetric) to describe these  quadratic equations.

Then is it possible to turn this set of $N$ equations, into $2^N$ linear equations? That is to say, find a matrix $M$ of size $2^N\times 2^N$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j}^{2^N}M_{ij}\tilde{x}_j=\lambda \tilde{x}_i,\quad \forall 1\leq i \leq 2^N
\end{equation}
Such that the solution $\tilde{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{2^N}$ gives the same solution for the quadratic case.

Comment: "$\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ are constants"; Are the two values of $\lambda$ different constants ($\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$) or is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, they are different constants. If I am not mistaken for pair of solution, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ but I need to check it. I will edit my question and add precisions once I clarified it for myself.